# Pandas Timestamp - Cannot convert arg to a time error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the `min()` value between two points using `between_time`.  I have created two columns that I would like to use as my start and end time to find the minimum value and add the output to a new column:

This is a snip of the df:

```
df[['Date_Time','d1_idx_last','Low']]



                                   Date_Time    d1_idx_last              Low
Timestamp           
2015-09-01 09:30:00.000 2015-09-01 09:30:00.000 2015-09-01 16:14:51.000 1887.750
2015-09-01 09:30:01.000 2015-09-01 09:30:01.000 2015-09-01 16:14:51.000 1888.250
2015-09-01 09:30:01.200 2015-09-01 09:30:01.200 2015-09-01 16:14:51.000 1888.000
2015-09-01 09:30:10.100 2015-09-01 09:30:10.100 2015-09-01 16:14:51.000 1889.250
2015-09-01 09:30:11.100 2015-09-01 09:30:11.100 2015-09-01 16:14:51.000 1889.500
```

I am trying to use this code:

```
df.Low.between_time(df.Date_Time, df.d1_idx_last, include_start=True, include_end=True)
```

and get this error:

```
Cannot convert arg [1441099800000000000 1441099801000000000 1441099801200000000 ...,
 1470924200100000000 1470924369230000000 1470924793157000000] to a time
```

The columns `'Date_Time'` & `'d1_idx_last'` are both type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`.

**Update to clarify:**

So if we look at the first row it shows

`'Date_Time' 2015-09-01 09:30:00.000`
`'d1_idx_last'2015-09-01 16:14:51.000`

On this row the time between `'Date_Time'` & `'d1_idx_last'` captures a full trading day (09:30-16:15) and I want the low of the time between these two points.

On this day the market went as low as 1863.500 so that would be the min value for (09:30-16:15).

```
df[['Low']]['2015-09-01'].min()

Low   1863.500
dtype: float64
```

If the low of 1863.500 came at 13:00 the rolling low would be higher after this point.

I want a new column called `df['subset_low']` that checks `'Date_Time'` & `'d1_idx_last'` on each row and finds the low between this period and adds it to df['subset_low'].  It is checking the current time and the last point of the day and showing what the low will be between this time.

Another example for @Maxu using fake data in the `Low` and (desired) `subset_low` columns:
[image]

Comment: You need to pass `between_time` scalar values - not a Series object...

Comment: Would I do this by using `apply` to implement on a per row basis?  Can anyone help fix my code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** using ugly method - `apply(..., axis=1)`:

```
In [170]: df['subset_low'] = df.apply(lambda r: df.query('@r.Date_Time <= index <= @r.d1_idx_last').Low.min(), axis=1)

In [171]: df
Out[171]:
                                      Date_Time         d1_idx_last  Low  subset_low
idx
2015-09-01 09:30:00.000 2015-09-01 09:30:00.000 2015-09-01 16:14:51    2           1
2015-09-01 09:30:01.000 2015-09-01 09:30:01.000 2015-09-01 16:14:51    1           1
2015-09-01 09:30:01.200 2015-09-01 09:30:01.200 2015-09-01 16:14:51    3           3
2015-09-01 09:30:10.100 2015-09-01 09:30:10.100 2015-09-01 16:14:51    4           3
2015-09-01 09:30:11.100 2015-09-01 09:30:11.100 2015-09-01 16:14:51    3           3
```

**OLD answer:**

as @JonClements already [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944599/pandas-timestamp-cannot-convert-arg-to-a-time-error/38944679#comment65244189_38944599) the [between_time()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) method expects scalar values for the first two arguments- (`start_time`, `end_time`) and it checks only the time part.

Demo:

```
In [72]: df.between_time('09:30:10','09:30:15')
Out[72]:
                                      Date_Time         d1_idx_last      Low
idx
2015-09-01 09:30:10.100 2015-09-01 09:30:10.100 2015-09-01 16:14:51  1889.25
2015-09-01 09:30:11.100 2015-09-01 09:30:11.100 2015-09-01 16:14:51  1889.50
```

You can use [query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method instead

```
In [70]: df.query('Date_Time <= index <= d1_idx_last')
Out[70]:
                                      Date_Time         d1_idx_last      Low
idx
2015-09-01 09:30:00.000 2015-09-01 09:30:00.000 2015-09-01 16:14:51  1887.75
2015-09-01 09:30:01.000 2015-09-01 09:30:01.000 2015-09-01 16:14:51  1888.25
2015-09-01 09:30:01.200 2015-09-01 09:30:01.200 2015-09-01 16:14:51  1888.00
2015-09-01 09:30:10.100 2015-09-01 09:30:10.100 2015-09-01 16:14:51  1889.25
2015-09-01 09:30:11.100 2015-09-01 09:30:11.100 2015-09-01 16:14:51  1889.50
```

How do I get the `min()` of `df.Low` between `Date_Time` and `d1_idx_last` using `df.query`?

```
In [74]: df.query('Date_Time <= index <= d1_idx_last').Low.min()
Out[74]: 1887.75
```

Comment: Thanks Maxu but how do I get the `min()` of `df.Low` between `Date_Time` and `d1_idx_last` using `df.query`?  The output from your code does not give this.

Comment: @adele, i've updated my answer - is that what you want?

Comment: the df has 148566 rows and I want to add a new column showing `min()` value of `df.Low` between `Date_Time` and `d1_idx_last` for each row.   I will be using this new column for further analysis later.  Do I need to use `apply` or `map` maybe to do this?  If i use the code you have it gives me one value instead of looking at each row. thanks for the help

Comment: @adele, it's not quite clear - could you post a desired data set?

Comment: What I am trying too get is essentially a rolling `min` between `Date_Time` and `d1_idx_last` on each row with a new column capturing the output called `df['subset_low']`.

Comment: @adele, i still don't get it - what would you have in the 2nd, 3rd, etc. rows? Can you provide a sample and desired data sets?

Comment: I have added an image to show why I need all rows.  thanks

Comment: @adele, sorry, i don't see any elegant solution (which wouldn't loop through all rows). Can you explain how are you going to use this new column - `subset_low`?

Comment: Having the `subset_low` would allow me to see how much drawdown is seen from any given point of the day to the end of the day.  I use this data to filter when working out basic statistics on the trade data.

Comment: So my original code that gave the error was `df.Low.between_time(df.Date_Time, df.d1_idx_last, include_start=True, include_end=True)`.  Is this not possible to use with apply or similar to apply on a per row basis if the code is tweaked?  thanks

Comment: I would also be interested in any code to give this output even if not elegant, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the efforts @Maxu.  If I also want to apply this on the `high` column would I use: `df['subset_high'] = df.apply(lambda r: df.query('@r.Date_Time <= index <= @r.d1_idx_last').High.max(), axis=1)`?  I will test and comment when done.

Comment: @adele, yes, you can do it this way